# If statements not working in batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I made this code for something to remind me about certain things I need to do, but for some reason the code isn't working.

```css
@echo off

cls
echo Welcome to ChoreHub
echo -------------------------------------------
echo Today's List:
echo * Do School
echo * Practice Piano
echo * Check to Make Sure House is Clean
echo * Check to Make Sure Room is Clean
echo -------------------------------------------
echo What chore have you finished? (1, 2, 3, 4)
set /P chore=
if %chore%=="1" goto :1 
if %chore%=="2" goto :2 
if %chore%=="3" goto :3 
if %chore%=="4" goto :4 
goto bro
```

When I put in a right answer, it skips over the if statements and goes straight to the bottom.
I'm not sure why, I am a little rusty on batch files though. If anyone could help me that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! From what I see, the goto targets (also known as "labels") `:1`, `:2`, `:3`, and `:4` are missing in your code example. I assume they exist in your code. If you don't post the complete code, chances are the error is hiding in the missing parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't set anything? where is 1,2,3 and bro? where is it supposed to go??

you need to add this

```
:1
echo 1 is selected
goto :end

2:
echo 2 is selected
goto :end

:3 
echo 3 is selected
goto :end


:end
```

check this [fully working batch example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411533/batch-file-choice-options-setting-default-option)

Comment: thank you so much! It looks like it was the quotations around the input answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing all your code, but I think, your problem is here:

```
if %chore%=="1" goto :1
```

You are comparing your variable with `"1"` (not just `1` what you seem to think)

You need to enter `"1"` ( Quote 1 Quote ) to match this.

Better code:

```
if "%chore%"=="1" goto :1
```

(Note: `if %chore%==1` seems to be correct too, but will give a syntax error, if `%chore%` is empty)